# Python 2.7.8 End of script output before headers: te.py

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, cgi-bin

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` using Vmware and working on `Python cgi-bin`. I am following this tutorial: http://archive09.linux.com/feature/136602 . My example1.py `"Hello, Linux.com!"` is printing successfully but example2.py is not and server is constantly saying:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: te.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

And the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
laptops = form.getvalue('laptops','0')
desktops = form.getvalue('desktops','0')
print """
<html>
<body>
<form action='second.py'>
How many laptops do you own?&nbsp;
<input type='radio' checked name='laptops' value='0' />0&nbsp;
<input type='radio' name='laptops' value='1' />1&nbsp;
<input type='radio' name='laptops' value='2' />2
<p>
How many desktops do you own?&nbsp;
<input type='radio' checked name='desktops' value='0' />0&nbsp;
<input type='radio' name='desktops' value='1' />1&nbsp;
<input type='radio' name='desktops' value='2' />2
<p>
<input type='submit' />
<p>
You own %d computers.
</form>
</body>
</html>""" % (int(laptops)+int(desktops))
```

I am myself fail and cannot figure out the reason. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have provided python path, can you check if you have provided execute permission to file ? I guess adding execute permission will resolve your error.

Comment: befor executing i made chmod +x example2.py

Comment: stilll same i dont know :( . I am on VM ware i forgot to write

Comment: well VM should not cause any issue as per my understanding

Comment: have you provided permission in /etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf ??

Comment: yes code looks okay, I feel like permissions are not given properly. 
may be in httpd.conf

Comment: i ve something like this /etc/httpd.conf

Comment: and directory path is /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

Comment: try to look for AllowOverride and make it all instead of none and restart apache

Comment: it need permission. i am aaplying "sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf" but not saving

Comment: i just add in top of page as header - print("Content-Type: text/html\n"). This resolved my issue.